# Xamarin app develpment set up for first run

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am currently trying to make a cross platform app (IOS + Android) using xamarin.

My problem at the moment is setting up. As soon as I make the project I got TONS of errors, missing references and the likes. I've been patching them one by one but as soon as I do they seem to double up and I think I'm doing something wrong. Also when running the app emulator for android I get a black screen (on phone window) and no functionality.

What is the correct way to set it up properly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems like you doesn't install all required components to make Xamarin development. Refer official documentation to setup your environment correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Android support libraries are either not properly installed or not properly configured either in the solution or in the machine.

To identify if it's in the solution, try creating a new Xamarin forms blank app and test it. If that is not working and results in same issues, then check whether you have installed all the required support libraries for the Android correctly.

Refer the below document links for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/windows 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?ide=vs&tabs=windows

If you think, it is already configured properly, then try doing a VisualStudio repair or uninstall and reinstall the visual studio again.

Note that you can also reconfigure the Android SDK manager alone if you are sure that your VisualStudio is fine and suspect that Android configuration is the problem.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, installing it properly fixed the errors, now I just need to figure out why the phone window is blank!